# Different setter behavior between DbContext and ObjectContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, dbcontext, objectcontext

(This is using EntityFramework 4.2 CTP)

I haven't found any references to this on the web yet, although it's likely I'm using the wrong terminology while searching.  There's also a very likely scenario where this is 100% expected behavior, just looking for confirmation and would rather not dig through the tt template (still new to this).

Assuming I have a class with a boolean field called Active and I have one row that already has this value set to true.  I have code that executes to set said field to True regardless of it's existing value.

- If I use DbContext to update the value to True no update is made.
- If I use ObjectContext to update the value an update is made
  regardless of the existing value.

This is happening in the exact same EDMX, all I did was change the code generation template from DbContext to EntityObject.

**Update:**

Ok, found the confirmation I was looking for...consider this a dupe...next time I'll do MOAR SEARCHING!

[Entity Framework: Cancel a property change if no change in value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463799/entity-framework-cancel-a-property-change-if-no-change-in-value)

**Update 2:**

*Answer (or at least the solution I found) moved to actual answer as requested...*

Comment: Please put your solution as an answer.

Comment: Once my 8 hour "self-answer" wait is up I'll post it if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, the answer to my own question (sorry)...

**Problem:**  the default tt template wraps the "if (this != value)" in the setter with "if (iskey), so only primarykey fields receive this logic.

**Solution:**  it's not the most graceful thing, but I removed this check...we'll see how it pans out in real usage.  I included the entire tt template, my changes are denoted with **...

**Update:** confirmed and worked around using same method in Entity-Framework 5 Beta 2

```
////////
////////  Write SimpleType Properties.
////////
private void WriteSimpleTypeProperty(EdmProperty simpleProperty, CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    MetadataTools ef = new MetadataTools(this);
#>

/// <summary>
/// <#=SummaryComment(simpleProperty)#>
/// </summary><#=LongDescriptionCommentElement(simpleProperty, 1)#>
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=       <#=code.CreateLiteral(ef.IsKey(simpleProperty))#>, IsNullable=<#=code.CreateLiteral(ef.IsNullable(simpleProperty))#>)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
<#=code.SpaceAfter(NewModifier(simpleProperty))#><#=Accessibility.ForProperty(simpleProperty)#> <#=MultiSchemaEscape(simpleProperty.TypeUsage, code)#> <#=code.Escape(simpleProperty)#>
{
    <#=code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(simpleProperty))#>get
    {
<#+             if (ef.ClrType(simpleProperty.TypeUsage) == typeof(byte[]))
            {
#>
        return StructuralObject.GetValidValue(<#=code.FieldName(simpleProperty)#>);
<#+
            }
            else
            {
#>
        return <#=code.FieldName(simpleProperty)#>;
<#+
            }
#>
    }
    <#=code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter((simpleProperty)))#>set
    {
<#+
        **//if (ef.IsKey(simpleProperty)) 
        **//{
            if (ef.ClrType(simpleProperty.TypeUsage) == typeof(byte[]))
            {
#>
        if (!StructuralObject.BinaryEquals(<#=code.FieldName(simpleProperty)#>, value))
<#+
            }
            else
            {
 #>
        if (<#=code.FieldName(simpleProperty)#> != value)
<#+
            }
#>
        {
<#+
    PushIndent(CodeRegion.GetIndent(1));
        **//}
#>
        <#=ChangingMethodName(simpleProperty)#>(value);
        ReportPropertyChanging("<#=simpleProperty.Name#>");
        <#=code.FieldName(simpleProperty)#> = <#=CastToEnumType(simpleProperty.TypeUsage, code)#>StructuralObject.SetValidValue(<#=CastToUnderlyingType(simpleProperty.TypeUsage, code)#>value<#=OptionalNullableParameterForSetValidValue(simpleProperty, code)#>, "<#=simpleProperty.Name#>");
        ReportPropertyChanged("<#=simpleProperty.Name#>");
        <#=ChangedMethodName(simpleProperty)#>();
<#+
    **//if (ef.IsKey(simpleProperty))
        **//{
    PopIndent();
#>
        }
<#+
        **//}
#>
    }
}
```