# Set value as not modified if property value is equal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, composite-key, change-tracking

I'm having a problem with transfering child entities from one parent to another due to that the entity child have a composite primary key, that also is part of the foreign key

Technically speaking its the same issue as
[Entity Framework: Cancel a property change if no change in value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463799/entity-framework-cancel-a-property-change-if-no-change-in-value)

But from that 8 years have passed, and some other solutions should now exist?

The best solution that i came up with so far is this:

```
    public void CleanModified()
    {
        foreach (var entityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                .Where(w => w.State.HasFlag(EntityState.Modified)))
        {
            foreach (var currentValuesPropertyName in entityEntry.CurrentValues
                                                                    .PropertyNames)
            {
                var nop = entityEntry.Property(currentValuesPropertyName);

                if (!nop.IsModified)
                    continue;

                if (Object.Equals(nop.CurrentValue, nop.OriginalValue))
                    nop.IsModified = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Sadly this doesnt work and just throws the same exception i got in the first place on `nop.IsModified = false;`

```
The property '[CompositeKeyProperty]' is part of the object's key information 
and cannot be modified
```

I havn't worked anything with T4 so i dont know if that can help me in this case?

Added the following example:

Entities

```
public class Parent
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings

```
public class ParentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
    public ParentConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(k => new { k.TenantId, k.Id });

        Property(p => p.TenantId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

public class ChildConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public ChildConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(k => new { k.TenantId, k.Id });

        Property(p => p.TenantId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasRequired(r => r.Parent).WithMany(m => m.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(f => new { f.TenantId, f.ParentId });
    }
}
```

Program

```
public void Main()
{
    //Just example, fetched from database in real code
    Parent parentOld = new Parent
    {
        TenantId = 1,
        Id = 1,
        Children = { new Child { TenantId = 1, Id = 1, ParentId = 1 } }
    };

    Parent parentNew = new Parent { TenantId = 1, Id = 2 };

    //Move child from oldParent to newParent
    foreach (var parentOldChild in parentOld.Children)
    {
        //Throws 'The property 'TenantId' is part of the object's key information 
        //and cannot be modified'
        parentOldChild.Parent = parentNew; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you accidentally referencing same `ChangeTracker` object more than once to check modified state (by different context)? Often this error occurs in foreach loop and resolved by assigning new instance of that object inside loop body.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto No it is all in the same single context and access is routed directly to the underlying DbContext

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that the issue is because you're trying to set the `IsModified` state of a field that's part of the entity's key columns. Are you sure that the entity you're looking at isn't a new one? That might be a scenario where the `CurrentValue` is equal to the `OriginalValue`, yet `IsModified` is still true and can't be changed.

Comment: Added some more example code, the first example code tries to revert the change the second example casues, by touching the 'TenantId' it triggers a change update in the changetracker

Comment: Is TenantId part of the key of the table?

Comment: Yes, i have updated the post with a simplified example